# deprecated constructor wp_soundpress_plugin

Tags: wordpress, deprecated, construct

After updating to the latest wordpress, i came across an error message when i load the website:

Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; wp_soundpress_plugin has a deprecated constructor in:
../wp-content/plugins/soundpress/soundpress.php on line 107

This is what i see on line 107:
class wp_soundpress_plugin extends WP_Widget {

```
// constructor
function wp_soundpress_plugin() {
    parent::__construct(false, $name = __('SoundPress Widget', 'wp_soundpress_plugin') );
}
```

What do I replace this I wonder?
Thank you:-)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor functions in PHP should be named __construct. You can update the constructor function name from 'wp_soundpress_plugin' to '__construct' so it looks like this:

```
// constructor
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(false, $name = __('SoundPress Widget', 'wp_soundpress_plugin') );
}
```

However, this is only a bandaid fix and will be reverted if a plugin update is made and the constructor name issue hasn't been fixed by the plugin developer. It would be a good idea to contact the plugin developer and have them update their code, then update it via the Wordpress repository.